# Locally a Deligne-Mumford stack has a finite etale covering

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

This is a part of the proof of corollary 6.1.1 of Laumon, Moret-Bailly's "Champs Algeriques".

> Let $S$ be a scheme and $\mathscr{X}$ a non empty quasi-separated Deligne-Mumford stack over $S$.
> Then there exists a non empty open substack $\mathscr{U}$ of $\mathscr{X}$, an affine scheme $X$, and a finite etale morphism of constant degree $X \to \mathscr{U}$.

The authors say that this is clear.
But I have no idea to show it.

For example, if $\mathscr{X}$ has a proper covering, then this is trivially true.
(Since the degree is locally constant function.)
But what about the general case?

Comment: @WillSawin Sorry, it's my mistake. This is a part of the proof of 6.1.1. The authors do not use the theorem to state it. I'll edit.

Comment: I suppose you refer to condition (i), as stated in Theorem 6.1; notice that a similar fact is used in the proof of Corollary 5.7.2.